# react native memory leak react navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I want to check If the user has a secure Token in a useEffect but I get this error Message.

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
```

This happens when I use the useEffect. If I remove it, then I get no error message but I need to check if the user has the token.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import getSecureKey from '../utilies/getSecureKey';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AppStack = ({ navigation }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    getSecureKey().then(res => console.log(res)).catch(e => console.log(e));
  }, []);

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator showIcon={true} initialRouteName="AppTabs">
      <Stack.Screen name="AppTabs" component={AppTabs} options={{headerTitle: () => <Header />, headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
      }}} />

 .....
```

getSecureToken:

```
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';

const getSecureKey = async () => {
  const key = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('jwt');
  return key;
};

export default getSecureKey;
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './src/redux/store/index';
import AppStack from './src/navigation/stack';

const getFonts = async () => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    "nunito-regular": require("./assets/fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf"),
    "nunito-bold": require("./assets/fonts/Nunito-Bold.ttf"),
  });
};

const App = () => {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

  if(fontsLoaded) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer><AppStack /></NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>)
  } else {
    return (<AppLoading startAsync={getFonts} onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)} onError={() => {}} />)
  }
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't restore token in the navigator. Instead do this -

Firstly, install `expo-app-loading` from [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/)

Then, create a folder called `navigation` where your `App.js` is located. Then inside it create a File called `AppNavigator.js`.

Inside `AppNavigator.js`, paste this

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import getSecureKey from '../utilities/getSecureKey';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AppNavigator = () => {
  // Remove these Lines --
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   getSecureKey()
  //     .then((res) => console.log(res))
  //     .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  // }, []);

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator showIcon={true} initialRouteName="AppTabs">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="AppTabs"
        component={AppTabs}
        options={{
          headerTitle: () => <Header />,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
          },
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default AppNavigator;
```

For your `fonts` create a folder called `hooks` where your `App.js` is located and inside that create a file `useFonts.js`

In `useFonts.js` write like this -

```
import * as Font from "expo-font";

export default useFonts = async () => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    "nunito-regular": require("./assets/fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf"),
    "nunito-bold": require("./assets/fonts/Nunito-Bold.ttf"),
  });
};
```

In your `App.js`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import useFonts from "./hooks/useFonts";

import getSecureKey from './utilities/getSecureKey';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';

export default function App() {
  const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);

  // Always perform Token Restoration in App.js just to keep code clear.    
  const FontAndTokenRestoration = async () => {
    await useFonts(); // Font is being loaded here
    const token = await getSecureKey();
    if (token) {
      console.log(token);
    }
  };

  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={FontAndTokenRestoration}
        onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}
        onError={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I have one question. I already use Apploading to load fonts. How I can load two functions ?

Comment: Yes you can do that too in using `AppLoading`. Show me how you  are loading fonts. I may tell you a better way to do it. Update it in the question

Comment: thank you for your time! I updated my app.js file above :)

Comment: it works thanks!! Is that ok If the token exists that I dispatch an Api there? because I have to load user datas. I know how to do it I only ask If this a good way

Comment: Yes, its perfectly fine.